# LOAD DATA FROM S3 command failing because of timestamp

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector, amazon-aurora

I'm running the ["LOAD DATA FROM S3"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html) command to load a CSV file from S3 to Aurora MySQL. The command works fine if run it in the Mysql Workbench (it gives me the below exception as warnings though but still inserts the dates fine), but when I run it in Java I get the following exception:

```
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: 
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2018-05-16T00:31:14-07:00'
```

Is there a workaround? Is there something I need to setup on the mysql side or in my app to make this transformation seamless? Should I somehow run a REPLACE() command on the timestamp?

---

**Update 1:**

When I use REPLACE to remove the "-07:00" from the time original timestamp (2018-05-16T00:31:14-07:00) it loads the data appropriately. Here's my load statement:

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://bucket/object.csv'  
REPLACE  
INTO TABLE sample  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@myDate) 
SET `created-date` = replace(@myDate, '-07:00', ' ');
```

For obvious reasons it's not a good solution. Why would the LOAD statement work in the mysql workbench and not in my java code? Can I set some parameter to make it work? Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it is by using mysql's SUBSTRING function in the 'SET' part of the LOAD DATA query (instead of the 'replace'):

```
SUBSTRING(@myDate, 1, 10)
```

This way the trailing '-07:00' was removed (I actually opted to remove the time as well, since I didn't need it, but you can use it for TIMESTAMPS as well.